# what's the usage of libcurl internal socket (the argument sockfd) in libcurl?

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

I read about the page about `curl_multi_socket` interface below :

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_socket_action.html

It's described this function :

```
curl_multi_socket_action(CURLM * multi_handle,
                                   curl_socket_t sockfd,
                                   int ev_bitmask,
                                   int *running_handles);
```

what's the usage of 2nd arguments called `sockfd`?

Comment: It's not called `curl_socket_t`, it's called `sockfd` which is of type `curl_socket_t`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, thx for reminding